# Can ip sets (netfilter ipset) be used for mac based filtering only?

Tags: iptables, netfilter

As per ipsets man page - they allow one to match a set of IP addresses in one scoop as opposed to writing rules per IP address in iptables.

IP Sets do also allow ip:mac sets - which associates IP addresses and MAC addresses.

Is there a way I can create MAC address only sets in IP sets? So far looking at the documentation and some code - it doesn't appear so.

Follow up question if the answer to question above is no - "If one has to implement such sets - hashmap should be a preferred choice?"

Requirements are at the most few tens of MACs to be associated to a "set". I agree such a thing won't be to hard in iptables itself, but it's too kludgy, and very hard to maintain (if those groups should be dynamic for any reasons).

Or am I missing something?

Edit 1: I did miss something indeed! ebtables allows to match a MAC amongst a list read from a file and can mark frames. http://linux.die.net/man/8/ebtables . Manual also suggests that it's possible to link this to iptables through the mark action. Will dig deeper and post further.

Answer (score 1):

The support for hash:mac type was added in ipsets in the following commit.

http://git.netfilter.org/ipset/commit/?id=4652cd11938b7ed2ad16cbb80698caa44b0e53bb

So the short answer "Yes!" ipsets does support mac based sets to be created.

Comment: can you please mention some example rule to create a mac based ipset.

Comment: I've done this long time back. Give me some time to check it and get back.

Comment: I'm stuck on this same issue. Any extra info?

Answer (score 1):

As indicated by @gabhijit himself, [ipset added this feature](http://git.netfilter.org/ipset/tree/ChangeLog) in version **6.22** back in 2014 (it got documented a few days later in v6.23). However, not every kernel supports it (e.g., Debian *jessie* doesn't, even though it includes v6.23, but *stretch* should).

Use `sudo modinfo ip_set_hash_mac` to see if your kernel supports the `hash:mac` set type.

Use `ls /lib/modules/*/kernel/net/netfilter/ipset/` to find all supported set types (works at least using Debian).